# OSMNX/networkx projection disconnects nodes

Tags: networkx, osmnx

I would like to create a map of isolines for a given country.

I fetched road map using OSMNX:

```
cf = '["highway"~"motorway|motorway_link|trunk|primary|secondary"]'
G = ox.graph_from_place('Venezuela', network_type='drive', custom_filter=cf)
# project the graph to UTM
G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
```

Then I created a subgraph of all nodes within given radius from starting point (lat, long):

```
node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (8.284904228184445, -62.72239713960212))
subgraph = nx.ego_graph(G_projected, node, radius=10000, distance="length")
```

Resulting subgraph contains only 1 node (no matter what radius is used)

```
list(subgraph.nodes())
[5098062996]
```

List of neighbours is empty:

```
list(G_projected.neighbors(5098062996))
```

But for graph G (before projection was conducted):

```
list(G.neighbors(5098062996))
[5098062995]
```

The CRS of the starting point is EPSG:4326, WGS 84, project_graph projects it to UTM zone in which the graph’s centroid lies. But what is the resulting CRS, I guess that in this case, it is also WGS 84 because there is no difference in terms of geometry between results for G and G_projected. Is it necessary to project G to UTM each time, and what about the disconnected nodes, is it the result of projection operation?

Following methods turned out to be not very helpful in identifying the problem:

```
list(nx.isolates(G_projected))
list(nx.isolates(G))
```

Both return empty list. Which mean that every node has neighbours (is connected?)

Given node is also in the list of connected components of a graph:

```
5098062996 in list(nx.connected_components(G_projected.to_undirected()))[0]
True
```

We have contradicted information, the node is connected but has no neighbours and resulting subgraph contains only the starting point.

I have to emphasise that for different nodes everything work fine, I encountered issues only with that particular node. For G without projection it works. I only used the projection because I saw it in notebook examples at OSMNX github page.

I should simply do not use the projection or I should use it and there is some other issue with the graph connectivity?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your exact query because getting the graph for all of Venezuela requires over 700 downloads. But I can reproduce your area of interest around that point, and everything appears to be working correctly:

```py
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

pt = 8.28490, -62.72240
cf = '["highway"~"motorway|motorway_link|trunk|primary|secondary"]'
G = ox.graph_from_point(pt, dist=5000, network_type='drive', custom_filter=cf)
G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)

node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, pt)
print(list(G.neighbors(node))) #[]
print(list(G_projected.neighbors(node))) #[]
print(list(G.predecessors(node))) #[5098062995]
print(list(G_projected.predecessors(node))) #[5098062995]

x = G.nodes[node]['x']
y = G.nodes[node]['y']
bbox = ox.utils_geo.bbox_from_point((y, x), dist=200, project_utm=True)
nc = ['r' if n==node else 'w' for n in G.nodes()]
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G_projected, node_color=nc, node_size=50, bbox=bbox)
```

[image]

The node in question is [this one](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/5098062996), which given the network types in your custom filter, has no successor nodes in your graph. For a MultiDiGraph, `neighbors` is [equivalent](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.MultiDiGraph.neighbors.html) to `successors` and thus in both the unprojected and projected graphs, you get an empty list (and an empty subgraph when induced on this node). This node does however have one [predecessor](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/5098062995) in your graph, which you can see printed in the code snippet using the `predecessors` method.